# Db2 stored procedure accepts user defined arraylist

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, db2

Can someone please help me to find out, the process to create a stored procedure in db2 which accepts userdefined object Arraylist and call it from hibernate.

Actually the requirement is i will get list of user defined objects i need to validate them against db and need to sent back the reposne with true or false flag appended.

Thank You.

Comment: "user defined objects" where -- in your Java code or in the database? I doubt you can do this using Hibernate, as the Db2 dialect implementation is quite date. Here's the [manual page describing the general approach](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_c0052030.html).

Comment: User defined object in java..

Comment: You can only pass something that maps to a SQL data type to a stored procedure, so you can't pass an array of arbitrary Java objects to it. You probably want to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

db2 query excepts TABLE as parm to simulate an array list.

```
select * from ? a join ? b on a._id = b._id
```